# Selenium Python: How to select item from a dropdown

Tags: python, selenium

I am able to open the dropdown menu however I am unable to click any option on the dropdown menu. This is the error I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="j_c40"]/li[3]"}`
```

This works fine by opening the dropdown menu:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='va-sm-m']").click()
```

This should press an option from the dropdown but gives me an error.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_c40"]/li[3]').click()
```

The code from the site from where I want to select looks like this:

```
<li tabindex="0" data-size="EU M 39 / W 39" class="js-select size size-two-column ncss-brand va-sm-m d-sm-ib va-sm-t ta-sm-c " data-provide="sizes.1"><span>EU M 39 / W 39</span></li>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Full code:

```
self.driver.get("https://www.nike.com/de/launch/")
    ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "cookie-settings-layout")))
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cookie-settings-layout"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='va-sm-m']").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_c40"]/li[3]').click()
```

Here is the link from the dropdown:

```
https://www.nike.com/de/launch/t/air-vapormax-utility-black-orange-peel
```

Comment: Can you paste in a large snippet of HTML so we can see more context?

Comment: Selenium might be trying to click it before it is visible, maybe use an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)?

Comment: @aylr updated the code

Comment: @Sid Why wouldn't you just show your whole script so we could run it then?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code allowed me to select the EU M 39 / W 39 option from the dropdown menu.

```
# navigate to the website with dropdown
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/de/launch/t/air-vapormax-utility-black-orange-peel')

# select the dropdown button once it is availble
dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'j_c38')))

# click the dropdown button
dropdown.click()

# find all list elements in the dropdown. 
# target the parent of the button for the list
li = dropdown.parent.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

# click the second element in list
li[1].click()
```

Comment: how would I select the buy button? <a href="#" class="js-buy ncss-brand ta-sm-c u-uppercase pt3-sm pr5-sm pb3-sm pl5-sm pt2-lg pb2-lg d-sm-b d-lg-ib test-buyable ncss-btn bg-black text-color-white">Kaufen 210,00&nbsp;€</a>

Comment: dropdown.parent.find_element_by_class_name('js-buy').click()